# How to create a file in the cloud function and upload to a bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

For some time now, I've been trying to create a file (sample.txt) containing some text (hello world) and finally uploading it into a bucket. Is there a way I can implement this?. My attempted code is below:

```
exports.uploadFile = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), "sample.txt");

    await fs.writeFile(tempFilePath, "hello world");
    const bucket = await admin.storage().bucket("allcollection");

    await bucket.upload(tempFilePath);
    return fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(error);
  }
});
```

Anytime this code is run I get and error like this in there firebase console:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function 
 at maybeCallback (fs.js:128:9) 
  at Object.writeFile (fs.js:1163:14)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what exactly isn't working with the code you have now, including whatever debugging information you have.  I suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sure I will do that

Answer (score 1):

You're not using [fs.writeFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) correctly.  As you can see from the linked documentation, it takes 3 or 4 arguments, one being a callback.  The error message is saying you didn't pass a callback.  On top of that, it doesn't return a promise, so you can't effectively await it.  Consider using [fs.writeFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) instead to make this easier.